# Adding bitmap in Access 2013

Tags: ole, ms-access-2013

I am trying to add a bmp in a table I created in Access 2013. The steps I followed were, right click on the table cell -> insert object -> create from file -> browse and selected the bmp file that needs to be added.

When I added the file, I see the word "Package" in the cell instead of the image. But I need to display the image. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

To access recognize the image as a bitmap and paint in a field visually, you can not add it from the file where you have the image, but it will look like a package.

You must do the following:

1. Right-click over the table field (OLE Object) where you want to put the image.
2. In the options listed, click insert object.
3. Choose the radio button with the option Create New.
4. Select from the list of available options, the option Bitmap Image.
5. Microsoft Paint program opens. You must paste the image you want to insert in Paint and save.
6. Once saved you can close the Paint and see that in the field image shown.